How do I exclude XML documentation of partial classes autogenerated by Mvvm Toolkit?
I have benefited a great deal from Mvvm Community Toolkit in a project, and also used DefaultDocumentation, another great NuGet package, to convert my XML comments into Markdown files readable on the Github repository of the project.
However, I have been noticing that DefaultDocumentation also pick up the XML comments from partial classes autogenerated by the Toolkit and place them in the .md files, causing a clutter around my API documentation.
This is obviously not a big deal, but I am trying to reach anyone who might know about some configuration files which I can modify, so that those two packages won't know or care about each other's handiworks. All I saw are some old questions about suppressing missing XML comments in autogenerated files, which is not what I want. There must be some ways to exclude certain files from the consideration of DefaultDocumentation package, but I can't even find the code files of partial classes autogenerated by the Toolkit.
